# What territory would the Aozaki Clan have?

Tags: tsukihime, mahoutsukai-no-yoru

The Tohsaka have Fuyuki, and it was because of that they were apart of the Heaven's Feel ritual at first (because Fuyuki was a spritual land that the Makiri (Matou) and the Einzbern needed).
The Aozoki, while not as great of a Magi Clan as the Tohsaka, was still a good clan.
Did they become Second Owners of any territory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [Q&A with Nasu Kinoko](http://completematerial.pbworks.com/w/page/34267021/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions#Misc.) in *Fate/complete material III*, the Aozaki territory that the family are administrators of, while currently unnamed, resides in Japan.

It's mentions that these lands are the only place where True Magic can be activated and considered the greatest spiritual land in Japan.

*Mahoutsukai no Yoru* reveals that this land is indeed [Misaki Town](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Misaki_Town). It's mentioned in *Fate/complete material III* that the distance between Fuyuki City and Misaki Town is equivalent to the distance of Kanto and Kyushu.

Comment: so then the Aozaki territory would be Misaki Town and surrounding area's since Mahou Tsukai no Yoru is set there and Aoko first performs the 5th True magic there when fighting Touko